# How to sanitize user input in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to sanitize user input in mongoose. I though that using mongoose middleware would help, but it seems that I am either wrong or I am doing something wrong.

The reason I am trying to use Mongoose middleware (and not Express middleware) is that I have a document that can have a nested document - however, that nested document can be a standalone document as well. I am trying to create a "single point of truth" for my documents so that I can sanitize only in one place.

The following code does not seem to work:

```
Organization.pre("validate", function (next) {
  this.subdomain = this.trim().toLowerCase();
  next();
});
```

PS. I am also using mongoose-validator, which in turn uses node-validator to validate the user input - node validator also has some sanitize methods, maybe I should use them somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case I think it would be better to add [`trim: true`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_string_SchemaString-trim) to the `Organization` schema definition for `subdomain`:

```
subdomain: { type: String, trim: true }
```