# Sanitize user input in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Except for [this fairly uninformative answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11987873/how-to-sanitize-user-input-in-mongoose) and another [unpopular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18318798/sanitizing-data-before-saving-to-mongoose), I can't seem to find any resources about sanitizing user input using Mongoose.

There's a [blog post here](https://thecodebarbarian.wordpress.com/2014/09/04/defending-against-query-selector-injection-attacks/) about Node/MongoDB injection which seems good at the server level, but there must be something in the middleware level (i.e. Mongoose) that can sanitize input and ensure reasonable safety in the database.

Is there such a beast, or is it even necessary?

Comment: @JohnnyHK you seem to be an expert here - can you weigh in?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It seems like the [mongo-sanitize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-sanitize) npm module is the place to start for the raw escaping functionality. Honestly this sounds more appropriate at the connect/express middleware layer because at the mongoose layer, by design, the code does not exert any expectations on the query/update parameters in terms of whether they are written by the application developer (in which case they must not be sanitized or they won't function correctly) or involve user input (which must be sanitized). Thus I'd recommend middleware functions to sanitize the most common places for user input to enter: `req.body`, `req.query`, and `req.params`. So for example you might do something like (sketch):

```
var json = require("body-parser").json;
var sanitize = require("mongo-sanitize");

function cleanBody(req, res, next) {
  req.body = sanitize(req.body);
  next();
}

function updateUser(req, res) {
  //...
  // safe to build an update query involving req.body here
}
app.put("/api/users", json(), cleanBody, updateUser);
```

Comment: `For the passionately lazy...` I like it already - looks like that's what I was looking for.  Your point about sanitizing before passing to the data model layer makes a lot of sense. Thanks Peter, and great website BTW.

Comment: Just tried this out, works as advertised, easy to use.

Comment: Inspired by mongo-sanitize (express middleware): https://github.com/fiznool/express-mongo-sanitize

Answer (score 1):

There is a new tool providing auto control of coming URL and html body data. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/content-filter

Also native `escape()` method might be used for to protect the database.

Run the code snippet below to see the results.

```js
let a = "{$gt:25}"
console.log(a)
console.log(escape(a))
```

Comment: escape() isn't right for the web. It doesn't use HTML entitities and it escapes too much, including spaces.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But still it might be used for filtering `_id` and other specific fields. Also `content-filter` can be used for most of cases.