# Mitigating MongoDB injection attacks with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql-injection

I'm using the [Mongoose ODM wrapper](https://mongoosejs.com/) for NodeJS and I'm concerned about injection attacks. Let's assume I have the following schema:

```js
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ userName: String, password: String });
```

If I were to perform a login request that looks like the following:

```js
router.post('/login', (request, response) => {

    const userName = request.body.userName;
    const password = request.body.password;

    User.findOne({ userName: userName }, function (error, user) {
        // ... check password, other logic
    });
});
```

I would be open to an injection attack with the following JSON payload which will always find a user:

```js
{
    "email": { "$gte": "" },
    "password": { "$gte": "" }
}
```

I'm not concerned about the password as it is hashed if a user is found which prevents any actual log in but I want to make sure my input is sanitized so that an attacker wouldn't even make it to that point.

I'm aware of the [mongo-sanitize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-sanitize) NPM package referenced in a similar [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28710345/sanitize-user-input-in-mongoose) which appears to remove all JSON keys that begin with '$'. I plan on using this anyway but I will never allow the user to submit raw, unparsed JSON. Is it good practice in that case to just call toString() on the userName assuming I do the correct `null` checks?

```js
const userName = request.body.userName.toString();
```

That would eliminate the query from being executed but it doesn't feel very secure. I assume the following is a better approach as it tries to convert `userName` to a `String`:

```
User.findOne({ userName: { "$eq": userName } }, function (error, user) {
     // ... other logic
});
```

I can't find anything concerning this in the in the [Model.findOne() documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) which leads me to believe I'm overlooking something.

Any insight would be appreciated.

**Other References:**

1. https://blog.websecurify.com/2014/08/hacking-nodejs-and-mongodb.html
2. https://ckarande.gitbooks.io/owasp-nodegoat-tutorial/content/tutorial/a1_-_sql_and_nosql_injection.html

Comment: Simplest may be to reject the request if the posted `username` or `password` aren't strings. `if (typeof username !== 'string') ...`

Comment: I thought about that after asking the question. I wrote a middleware that sets the req.body.userName and req.body.password to empty strings if they're not strings but it feels very hacky and I have to add this middlware to every field for every paremeter. Is there no way to do this with Mongoose itself? Would that last { "$eq" : userName} statement be enough?

Comment: `$eq` would work fine as well. In general though, I'd argue that your express route is what should be performing any request format validation, not Mongoose. A valid POST /login should have userName and password string fields in the body of the request. If not, it should be rejected before it even gets to Mongoose.

Comment: This makes sense. I'm now starting to implement a Rails-esque strong parameter middleware for my routes to ensure correct parameter type and string escaping. If you put this as the answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While you could use `$eq` to ensure an equality comparison is used in the query, your express route handler is a better place to perform request format validation.

A valid `POST /login` should have `userName` and `password` string fields in the body of the request. If not, it should be rejected before it even gets to Mongoose.

Comment: can you share details on how to perform this check?  I.e. are you saying to simply do a `typeof request.body.userName === 'string'` or something else?

Comment: Right, that's the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, you can use npm package "**mongo-sanitize**" as given as per their documentation as below:

```
var sanitize = require('mongo-sanitize');

// The sanitize function will strip out any keys that start with '$' in the input,
// so you can pass it to MongoDB without worrying about malicious users overwriting
// query selectors.
var clean = sanitize(req.params.username);

Users.findOne({ name: clean }, function(err, doc) {
  // ...
});
```

If sanitize() is passed an object, it will mutate the original object.